# jQuery Mobile back button not showing up when linked to drop down UL

Tags: jquery-mobile

So I have one page that works perfectly fine, I am actually creating the links programatically and any link to get to the page with the working back button from is fine - I can see the back button no problem, but then I have a drop down that is just UL full of links and the two pages I link to from there don't show the back button.

Here is the top of the working page.

```
<div data-role="page" id="detailsPage" data-add-back-btn="true">
 <div data-role="header">
  <h1 id="title"></h1>
 </div>
```

There here is the one that doesn't work.

```
<div data-role="page" id="calendarPage" data-add-back-btn="true">
  <div data-role="header">
   <h1 id="title">Calendar</h1>
  </div>
```

Here is the UL that has the link to the calendar page that won't show a back button.

```
<div class="ui-block-b">
 <ul data-role="menu" id="optionsDropDown">
  <li>
   <span data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" data-iconpos="left">Calendar</span>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
     <li data-icon="false">
         <a href="#" id="thursdayFilter">Thursday</a>
      </li>
      <li data-icon="false">
         <a href="#" id="fridayFilter">Friday</a>
      </li>
      <li data-icon="false">
          <a href="#" id="listAllSessions">List All Sessions</a>
      </li>
      <li data-icon="calendar">
          <a href="#calendarPage" >Calendar</a>
      </li>
      <li data-icon="gear">
          <a href="#settingsPage" >Settings</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The back button on detailsPage always works, the back button on calendarPage never shows up. I have trolled the site but people seems to have issues when they mess with changeHash which I haven't touched.

Could I be screwing something up in the JS? I can't see anything obvious, I could post my whole JS file but I don't even touch these pages from there or mess with the links or anything. I thought maybe because the display is set to none on that list I just showed you above that it wouldn't work but then I tried changing that - it make no difference if you can see it initially or not. I don't get any errors in the console. I am so stumped at the moment. I hope someone can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is a possible cause but according to the docs, `data-role="button"` is only valid on `<a>`, `<button>` and `<input>` type elements. I don't see `<span>` listed there and wonder if that is affecting your navigation?

There is also no valid `data-role="menu"` attribute listed.

What version of jQuery Mobile are you using? Are you relying on any third party widgets?